# Ограничение по пользователю. ВК апи, Питон 3.х.х

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Код:

```
                if event.text.lower() == "/помощь":
                    if event.from_chat:
                        vk.messages.send(
                        chat_id=event.chat_id,
                        random_id=get_random_id(),
                        message='lol',
                )
```

Данный кусок кода отправляет при команде /помощь выводит lol
Необходимо сделать ограничение в виде:

пользователь1 ввел /помощь - нет ответа

пользователь2 ввел /помощь - есть ответ

user_id пробовал, не помогает.
Буду рад решению!

Comment: Покажите, как у вас не работает user_id

Comment: @gbg, ошибки - нет, проводили с пользователем тестовое сообщение - не работает, у обоих пользователей отправляется вывод.

Comment: Покажите код, сделайте пример, который позволит воспроизвести проблему

Comment: код указан выше, в вопросе. Более кода прилагать не стоит, ибо он однообразен. Все импорты и т.п. сделаны. 
Ссылка на фото-пример: https://imgur.com/a/G3e4vI7
Вставляя параметр user_id=*мой айди*, то он _ничего не менял_, просто как бы создавая пустую строку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот написал примитивное решение через текстовик, для примера. Если у вас есть база данных, то можно реализовать через неё

```
f = open("task.txt", 'r')# Содержание "task.txt"  4325342,543534,534543,54314,43
x = f.read()

txt1 = x.split(',')

g = 43# Допустим это айди пользователя

print(str(g) in txt1)# True
```

Comment: Благодарствую !